# jquery performance variable

Tags: jquery, performance, variables

few question, i want to know when i should use variable, if the selector will call more than one time, then i should variable that selector?

1. local or global variable? for example

`var $body = $('body');`

if i have 100 jquery function, each function need `$('body')` selector, local 100 time or global one time variable will faster?

2. if a function like below

   `$('.link').on('click', function() {
       var $this =$(this);
       $this.addClass('a');
     });`

the function is finish, only call $this one time, should i need `$this`? or just use `$(this)`? which one is faster?

3. variable non-selector

   `$('one').addClass('a').removeClass('b').html('abcd');
   $('two').addClass('a').removeClass('b').html('abcd');`

if i create a variable `var job = addClass('a').removeClass('b').html('abcd');`

```
`$('one').job;
$('two').job;`
```

will it be faster? or useless?

4. resize function variable, to made a full height div, which one will be faster?

   `$('#full-height').css({'height' : ($(window).height() + 'px')}); //without variable

   var vH = $(window).height();
   $('#full-height').css({'height' : vH + 'px'}); //with variable

   var vH = $(window).height();
   $('#full-height').height(vH + 'px'); //with variable and use height() method`

all of above function run inside `$(window).on('resize', function() {}`, so each time resize the function will run, will the variable code faster?

when i need to variable non-selector?

thanks soooo much

Comment: Do your own work. Use jsperf.com to measure the performance difference of two versions of code.

Comment: thank you for that good method to compare two version code, thanks :)  +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use an element multiple times, saving it in a variable **(a pointer for an element)** will improve performance for sure, because like you said it's a **query**, jQuery will fetch all the DOM to find the element that you need, so saving the result of a query in a variable will be faster, and it's a good habit.

So using `$this` instead of `$(this)` will improve performance too.

*For the Question 3

You can't do `job = addClass...` because addClass is **not a global functions!** it's a **jQuery object method!** so you can use it only with a jQuery object/element `$jqObject.addClass...`

*Question 4

Like I said if you are using a result of a method **multiple times in the same function**, you should put it in a variable, but in your example you are using the `$(window).height();` only one time, so puting it in variable is useless but it's a good habit for a **clean code**. and it will not affect performance.

So in simple words: if you are using a result of a method multiple times in the same context, saving it in a variable will improve performance.

Comment: thank you sooo much, very detail, about question 1, do you think that use global variable is better or not? thanks :)

Comment: It depends on what you want todo, but for an element like $body which is used very much, I think yeah it's better

Comment: thanks :) i want variable some element like $body or $html, thanks +1

Comment: Yes you can do it because these element are global anyway